# Moving with Die Probability

Tags: probability

The question is as follows: "Liz is standing on the real number line at position $0$. She rolls a die repeatedly. If the roll is $1$ or $2$, she takes one step to the right (i.e., the positive direction on the number line). If the roll is $3, 4, 5, $or $6,$ she takes two steps to the right. Let Xn be Liz’s position after n flips of the coin. Estimate the probability that $X_{90}$ is at least $169$"

Not sure how to start this. I don't need a solution, just an explanation of how to approach it

Comment: Let $n$ be the number of rolls $≥3$, so $90-n$ is the number of rolls $≤2$.  In order to reach $169$ we need $2n+(90-n)=n+90≥169\implies n≥79$.  You can do it by brute force (a machine's force, not yours) from here.  Or you can approximate with a normal.

Comment: Worth noting though:  This is an extremely low probability event...you only expect $n=60$ with a standard deviation of about $4.5$, so getting $n≥79$ is about a $4.25\sigma $ event.  That makes the approximations problematic...I'd just do the straight computation.

Comment: What do you mean by 169" ?

Comment: @Fareed AF the position on the number line after 90 rolls of the die.

Answer (score 1):

How many ways are there to get $169$ or more with $90$ rolls? The lowest of   $169$ is $(11, 1$ or $2$ plus $79, 3,4,5$ or $6$) and the highest $180$ is $ (90, 3,4,5$ or $6$). The probability of getting $169$ is $\binom{90}{11}\cdot (\frac{1}{3})^{11}\cdot (\frac{2}{3})^{79}$ So you end up with a sequence of $12$ terms where the next terms are $\binom{90}{10}\cdot (\frac{1}{3})^{10}\cdot (\frac{2}{3})^{80}$......etc

This isn't even close to an expected outcome so the probability will be really low.